# How to use If function in R to create a column using multiple conditions

Tags: r, database, if-statement, merge, multiple-columns

I am not familiar with R , I need your help for this issue ,
I have a data frame composed with 25 variables (25 columns) named df simplified

```
 name   experience      Club        age       Position 
 luc          2         FCB         18        Goalkeeper
 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
 ronaldo      14        FCB         32        Goalkeeper
 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
 messi        11        Liverpool   35        midfielder
 tevez        6         Chelsea     27        Attack
 inzaghi      9         Juve        34        Defender
 kwfni        17        Bayern      40        Attack
 Blabla       9         Real       25        midfielder
 wdfood      11        Liverpool   33        midfielder
 player2      7         Chelsea     28       Attack
 player3     10         Juve       34        Defender
 fgh         17        Bayern      40        Attack
```

I would like to add a column to this data frame named "country".This new column takes into account different conditions .

```
Juve      Italy
FCB       Spain
Real      Spain
Chelsea   England
Liverpool England
Bayern    Germany
```

So let say if the club is FCB or Real the value in country is Spain
the output of df$Country should be as follows

```
Country
Spain 
Spain 
Spain 
Spain 
England
England 
Italy 
Germany
Spain 
England 
England
Italy 
Germany
```

The code I started to do is the following

```
df$country=ifelse(df$Club=="FCB","spain",    df$Club=="Real","Spain" ......)
```

But it seems false .
knowing that my real data set has more than 250 different values in "club" column
and more than 30 in "Country"

doing that manually seems too long .

Could you help me in that point please .

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use `if-else` statements inside `for` loops? This would be the simplest way out.

Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 Club = c("FCB", "Real", "Liverpool"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$Club[i] == "FCB" | df$Club[i] == "Real"){
    df$country[i] <- "Spain"
  } else if(df$Club[i] == "Liverpool"){
    df$country[i] <- "England"
  } else{
    df$country[i] <- NA
  }
}

df
#   name      Club country
# 1    a       FCB   Spain
# 2    b      Real   Spain
# 3    c Liverpool England
```